# Why Divi shortcodes don't render in wp-json?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to use the `the_content` filter to process the Divi shortcodes, but the shortcodes are still appearing.  Specifically et_pb_section, et_pb_column, et_pb_text if that matters.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'content',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'ap3_divi_do_shortcodes',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );

    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'excerpt',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'ap3_divi_do_shortcodes',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
});

function ap3_divi_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request ) {

    global $post;
    $post = get_post($object['id']);

    // Set is_singular to true to avoid "read more issue"
    // Issue come from is_singular () in divi-builder.php line 73
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->is_singular = true;

    $output = array(
        'protected' => false
    );

    switch( $field_name ) {
        case 'content':
            $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
            break;
        case 'excerpt':
            $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );
            break;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Were you building a GatsbyJS headless front end for Divi?

Comment: I was using the AppPresser plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  I need to call `et_builder_add_main_elements()` but I also, had to make sure I only called it once.

```
define('ONLY_ONCE_ap3_divi_do_shortcodes', true);
```

Here is what I ended up with.

```
<?php

/**
 * Render the Divi shortcode in wp-json API
 * Placed in the wp-content/mu-plugins/ folder
 */

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'content',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'ap3_divi_do_shortcodes',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );

    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'excerpt',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'ap3_divi_do_shortcodes',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
});

function ap3_divi_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request ) {

    // Set is_singular to true to avoid "read more issue"
    // Issue come from is_singular () in divi-builder.php line 73
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->is_singular = true;

    // Set divi shortcode
    // The 2 function below are define in 'init' but they are call in 'wp'
    // REST Api exit after 'parse_request' hook, it's before 'wp' so divi's shortcode are not set
    if( !defined('ONLY_ONCE_ap3_divi_do_shortcodes') && function_exists('et_builder_init_global_settings') && function_exists('et_builder_add_main_elements') ) {
        define('ONLY_ONCE_ap3_divi_do_shortcodes', true);
        et_builder_add_main_elements();
    }

    //Define $post, if not defined, divi will not add outter_content and inner_content warper
    //Issue come from get_the_ID() in divi-builder.php line 69
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($object['id']);

    $output = array();

    //Apply the_content's filter, one of them interpret shortcodes
    switch( $field_name ) {
        case 'content':
            $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
            break;
        case 'excerpt':
            $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );
            break;
    }

    $output['protected'] = false;

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: This post was a lifesaver. Thanks.

Comment: This post saved my life, but now I am not able to edit any post using divi builder in Wordpress as it fails with a "Call to undefined function et_is_ab_testing_active()" error. Trying to find a solution right now..

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code below solved my problem thanks

```
if (function_exists('et_builder_add_main_elements')) {
    et_builder_add_main_elements();
}
```