# Accessing Wordpress Divi theme shortcodes in GraphQL layer as part of headless Wordpress build

Tags: wordpress, graphql, graphiql, divi, wp-graphql

I am working on an existing Wordpress site that uses a Divi child theme with the editor creating layouts with the Visual Editor. The client wants to develop a Gatsby site with data from a GraphQL layer provided by the [wp-graphql plugin](https://www.wpgraphql.com/).

When I access the REST API response for the pages that use these Divi layouts I get pure HTML for content and excerpts etc. However, when I access the GraphQL editor and make the same request using a GraphQL statement the content comes back with the Raw Divi shortcodes surrounded by one div tag.

My Graphql query is

```
query MyQuery {
  posts {
    nodes {
      content(format: RENDERED)
    }
  }
}
```

And it returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "content": "<div class=\"et-l et-l--post\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"et_builder_inner_content et_pb_gutters3\">\n\t\t[et_pb_sectionfb_built=&#8221;1&#8243; fullwidth=&#8221;on&#8221; _builder_version=&#8221;4.6.6&#8243; background_enable_image=&#8221;off&#8221;][et_pb_fullwidth_image.......
```

Where is should be returning just html as the api does:

```
<div class=\"et-l et-l--post\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"et_builder_inner_content et_pb_gutters3\">\n\t\t<div class=\"et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 et_pb_fullwidth_section et_section_regular\" >\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"et_pb_module et_pb_fullwidth_image et_pb_fullwidth_image_0\">
```

I have enabled the shortcodes to be rendered with the solution [Why Divi shortcodes don't render in wp-json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141887/why-divi-shortcodes-dont-render-in-wp-json). Any idea how I enable the shortcodes to be rendered in Graphql? Or if there is a setting or code I am missing in Divi?

Comment: I think this is more a support question for the graphql developers, as it's a very specific use-case. A quick google search turned up this related discussion: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23344

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Yes, I went through that and followed the recommended using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141887/why-divi-shortcodes-dont-render-in-wp-json. I did this and it surfaces rendered html in REST api but not GraphQL. I also consulted with Jason Dahl (the wp-graphql creator) and it's not something he has has a chance to look at. Just wondered if there was a setting script or setting I was missing as I thought the Graphql layer was a mirror of REST api

Comment: Divi has some quite unique caching mechanisms. Very likely, you need custom code to make Divi compatible with wp-graphql - you could either spend some time debugging the issue yourself, or find a developer who is familiar with Divi

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate